# how to pass input/output file to .m file using GUI?

Tags: user-interface, matlab, matlab-figure

i am begin matlab ,i how following matlab function , but how to pass input file(audio) path and ouput file (dat) path using GUI any body how idea help me  reply

```
function audio (FNameI, FNameO)
% FNameI: Input audio file (.wav, .au, ... )
% FNameO: Output bit stream file (.bit) or output data file (.dat)
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "pass using GUI"? you should give more details and possibly a code sample of what you tried, describing what didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

See the help file on the commands "uigetfile", "uiopen" and "uiputfile".